# Realtime landscape plus design program, final ground height

Tags: landscaping, hard-landscape, grading

I have Realtime Landscaping Plus 3D landscape design program and I cannot find any way to see what the the final height of the ground is in my design. The design has lots of slopes, height grids, terraces and such all overlayered and adding or subtracting from the final height. I need to figure out drainage, check the rise on slopes, and translate the design heights onto the yard and build it. How do I access the ACTUAL height of any given point in my design?

Comment: This is more of how to use software question than a gardening question.

Comment: I haven't used this programme, and some programmes are more useful than others, but so far as I'm aware, there should be some way to tell the programme what gradients should be and how high a particular terrace is going to be off the ground level. Whether you can then access a particular area and have it tell you what height it is, I've no idea. I prefer to do this kind of complicated thing by hand, so its all marked on the works drawing anyway...

Comment: I heard back from tech support at Idea Spectrum. What I have is not the 'pro' version and is for 'visualization purposes only' I am using the trial version and have collected about 300 3D plants from the sketchup warehouse, and I really like the program. Super easy. I will find some kind of work-around which involves moving around objects of a known height, and get my grade heights that way. Your plant knowledge is rather deep, by the way, you show up rather consistently on the tough plant I.D. questions.

Comment: Kevinsky you may move this post to where it needs to be. Or let me know how/where to move it, as I am new here, but I like it a lot.